# Enabling scroll bar for outer component only

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have an app that should display other components inside in a row.

The problem that I'm facing currently is when displaying the page with smaller resolution, no scroll is enabled and I can't see all components - I can see only the first row.

And still not showing the second line!

Comment: Hmm.. Could you append the essential code parts to the question itself. Your link may die and no point about what is the issue is otherwise visible.

Comment: I can see the codesandbox but I can't reproduce the issue. I have scrollbar anyway and I can scroll and see the other rows..

Comment: Hi Mosh. the issue that I have scroll bar on each project as well, and it shouldn't be that way. Project component should remain without scroll and the whole page should have a scroll. Hope I made my self clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see your blocks because of `body { overflow-y:hidden; }` in your `Login.css` while for .App-body you set `min-height: 100vh;` This means that upper `.App-body` blocks push others below "`overflow-y:hidden;`" line. That's why you see only 1 line of `.App-body` blocks.
And, please, never-ever use tag "body" inside your components!

Comment: Greet, thanks a lot. Can't recall why I disabled the scroll for the login, but anyway... I still have a huge space between first line and second one! How can I git rid of it?

Comment: Just remove `min-height: 100vh;` from `.App-body`. You use this class not only for a wrapper one, but in each block. That's why they are so tall

Answer (score 1):

In `App.css` for your body apply this lines of css, delete everything else. Remember `overflow-y:hidden;` hides all your content higher then the box size.
I also recommend to you check [w3schoools example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)

Or edit in your `Login.css` this

```
@import "../App.css";

body {
  /* overflow-y:hidden; */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

to this

```
    @import "../App.css";

     body {
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }
   /* @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    }*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I adapted your approach. Sorry that I can't accept your answer cause I already had accepted one.

Comment: No problem, don't worry, you can vote for the answer if you want ... I'm glad to help you.